# Why is is third colum lower than the others two?

Tags: html, css

[image]

My goal is simple. Making 3 columns of divs next to each other, but I can't figure out why the no. 3 column is lower than the others.

PS: I don't believe it's the header because I tried removing it and the problem remains.

Thanks for your help.

This is my HTML markup:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="head"> <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
       <h2>lorem ipsum?</h2></div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"> </div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.line {
  height: 20%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.centre {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20%;
}
.box {
  width: 10%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.head {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Please don't read only included because the post was to short.

Stackover flow is asking me to add more info but I feel like there is nothing more to add so here is incoherent ramblings about why is CSS so annoying to use or why I don't understand php why I don't know how to write half the symbols required while coding so I just ctrl c and ctrl v them in to the file from the intern because I am lazy to to find how to write them or the fact my code is incoherent mess because I can't be bothered to a explanation of what does what making is that I am the only one that can read my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` property to .line class

flex displays an element as a block-level flex container

```css
.line {
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.centre {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20%;
}
.box {
  width: 10%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.head {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="head"> <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
       <h2>lorem ipsum?</h2></div>



    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"> </div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
      <div class="left box"></div>
      <div class="centre box"></div>
      <div class="right box"></div>
    </div>
```